# Ambigious Column Name SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query which gets all the records of the particular table

My problem is I get an error in my query when im adding some column

my code:

```
SELECT AGENCY_TIER_I,AGENCY_TIER_II,article_name FROM ( SELECT * FROM
         (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ARTICLE_ID ORDER BY VERSION DESC) SEQ, *
         FROM EGPL_KB_ARTICLE_VERSION WITH(NOLOCK) ) AV
         WHERE AV.SEQ = 1 ) AV
         INNER JOIN EGPL_KB_ARTICLE A WITH(NOLOCK)
         ON AV.ARTICLE_ID = A.ARTICLE_ID
         INNER JOIN EGPL_KB_ARTICLE_DATA AD WITH(NOLOCK)
         ON AV.ARTICLE_REFERENCE_ID = AD.ARTICLE_REFERENCE_ID
```

this query runs fine

the problem occurs here:

```
SELECT AGENCY_TIER_I,AGENCY_TIER_II,article_name,article_id FROM ( SELECT * FROM
         (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ARTICLE_ID ORDER BY VERSION DESC) SEQ, *
         FROM EGPL_KB_ARTICLE_VERSION WITH(NOLOCK) ) AV
         WHERE AV.SEQ = 1 ) AV
         INNER JOIN EGPL_KB_ARTICLE A WITH(NOLOCK)
         ON AV.ARTICLE_ID = A.ARTICLE_ID
         INNER JOIN EGPL_KB_ARTICLE_DATA AD WITH(NOLOCK)
         ON AV.ARTICLE_REFERENCE_ID = AD.ARTICLE_REFERENCE_ID
```

When I add the article_id fields I get an error "ambigous column name article_id"
Is there anyway to solve this I am missing something? Thanks for your help

Comment: As a great man once said "Prefix your f*ing columns and this won't happen to you!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different `article_id` columns in your SQL (one from `AV`, one from `A`, and it doesn't know which one you want to return. Just alias the one you actually want to `SELECT`:

```
SELECT AGENCY_TIER_I,AGENCY_TIER_II,article_name,
     AV.article_id FROM ( SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ARTICLE_ID ORDER BY VERSION DESC) SEQ, *
     FROM EGPL_KB_ARTICLE_VERSION WITH(NOLOCK) ) AV
     WHERE AV.SEQ = 1 ) AV
     INNER JOIN EGPL_KB_ARTICLE A WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON AV.ARTICLE_ID = A.ARTICLE_ID
     INNER JOIN EGPL_KB_ARTICLE_DATA AD WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON AV.ARTICLE_REFERENCE_ID = AD.ARTICLE_REFERENCE_ID
```

(You should also alias the one you're using in the `PARTITION BY` statement, so that it doesn't cause you problems in the future. It could be somewhat ambiguous if you made a couple of changes to the query later as well.)

Comment: In this case, it may be best for him to alias both. you did. awesome.

Comment: @JustinE: I agree; I would alias both the one in the `SELECT` and the one in the `PARTITION BY`, just for clarity later. The one causing the issue now though is the one in the `SELECT` list, as the one in the `PARTITION BY` is unaliased also in the one the poster says works.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for this I was laughing to myself why I did not notice that well. Im just upset that someone downvote my question. thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2895518 You should properly prefix *all* of the columns with their table alias, not just the ones that *currently* break the query. Others may break the query later, and it also helps any reader understand which column comes from which table. The current query is a disaster waiting to happen; in the meantime, why make people guess?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the table alias for any field that occurs in more than one table.  Article_ID is in both AV and A (possibly more, but I can see that field exists in those 2 because of the join you're using), so anywhere you see Article_ID you need to preface it with either AV or A (depending on which table you want to pull it from).